# Conditionally prepend path to url in NGINX

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have this directory structure for my projects

```
/var/www
  /project-a
     /data    <-- configuration and user files/data 
     /app     <-- all the code is in sub-dirs in here
     /pm      <-- a home brew project management app
     /.pmdata <-- data used by pm
```

My goal is to configure NGINX so I can access the project itself through
http://project-a.dev/ and the project management with http://project-a.dev/pm/.

In other words, I want the second url preserved as is, but if the url does not point to `/pm/*` it should be re-written to have the missing `/app` prepended to it.

I have tried the following configuration but http://project-a.dev/pm/ results in 404 and http://project-a.dev/ first redirects to http://project-a.dev/app/ and then gives 404.

What am I doing wrong?

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    root /var/www/project-a;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name project-a.dev;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/app $uri/app/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could append `/app` to the `root` value for all URIs that do not begin with `/pm`. For example:

```
server {
    ...
    root /var/www/project-a/app;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
    location ^~ /pm {
        root /var/www/project-a;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        }
    }
}
```

The nested location block for `location ~ \.php$` executes PHP files within the `/pm` hierarchy. The `^~` modifier is necessary to avoid the other `location ~ \.php$` block taking control. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.